# How to use @Autowired in an class annotated with @Entity?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called *TimeBooking*. When I request this entity and return to the client I want to get a list of ActivityTimeBookings from a repository. But when the function get called the repo is null.
So I tried to @Autowired the repo and marked it as transient and also said Spring that there is a dependency which should be injected.

```
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
@Entity
public class TimeBooking extends BaseEntity{

    @Autowired
    private transient ActivityTimeBookingRepository activityTimeBookingRepository;

    ...

    @JsonProperty("activityTimeBookings")
    private List<ActivityTimeBooking> activityTimeBookings() {
        return this.activityTimeBookingRepository.findByDate(this.timeFrom);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't autowire things into an entity. It's just bad design (especially in the code you displayed).

Comment: Any other suggestions to get access to the repo in my case?

Comment: It's the wrong place to try to access a repository. That should be on the service layer, when you're building your resulting object.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@Autowired` in a class annotated with `@Entity` is a bad practice.

**The solution is given below :**

**1. Create a service interface :**

```
public interface TimeBookingService {

   public List<ActivityTimeBooking> activityTimeBookings();

}
```

---

**2. Create an implementation of the service interface :**

```
@Service
public class TimeBookingServiceImpl implements TimeBookingService {

    @Autowired
    private ActivityTimeBookingRepository activityTimeBookingRepository;

    public List<ActivityTimeBooking> activityTimeBookings() {
        return this.activityTimeBookingRepository.findByDate(this.timeFrom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually its indeed a bad practice to inject something into JPA entities.
These are usually created by JPA implementation (like Hibernate) and spring as a DI framework doesn't really participate in this process.

Note, that there can be many instances of this class created as a result of query, so if you later use this for serialization of the list of this object you might end up running N queries to the database given N entities like this were retrieved.

Answering your question about "getting access to the repo" I believe you should consider refactoring:

In the service class (assuming you have a "regular" contoller, service and dao):

you can:

```
class MyService {
    SomeResult.. doSomething() {
     List<TimeBooking> allTimeBookings = dao.getAllTimeBooking();
     LocalDateTime timeFrom = calculateTimeFrom(allTimeBookings);
     List<ActivityTimeBooking> allActivityTimeBookings = dao.findByDate(timeFrom);
     return calculateResults(allTimeBookings, allActivityTimeBooking);        
    }
}

class MyDao {
  List<ActivityTimeBooking> findByDate(LocalDateTime timeFrom) {...}

  List<TimeBooking> getAllTimeBookings() {...}
}
```

Regarding the service implementation, I've assumed this use case can't be covered by usual "JOIN between two tables" so that that creating an association between `TimeBooking` and `ActivityTimeBooking` is not an option.

Note 2, I've used one repository (dao) for brevity, in real application you might want to inject two different repositories into the service.