# How to use Autowire inside an @Entity in JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {

 InsuranceCompanyInvoiceCalculator insuranceCompanyInvoiceCalculator // how to autowire this?

 @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    Float ordersTotal;

    Float getOrdersTotal() {
        insuranceCompanyInvoiceCalculator.getOrdersTotal(this)
    }
}
```

I've looked at other questions like this one [How to use @Autowired in an class annotated with @Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197685/how-to-use-autowired-in-an-class-annotated-with-entity) but it doesn't answer the question at all. It suggests to create a @Service class. But still how do I autowire the @Service class from the @Entity class?

**EDIT**

I'm guessing that most people are advising that the construction of the Entity object should be done at the service layer where you will have access to @Autowire. But not in this case.

I'm using Spring Data/Spring Data Rest where your Entity is automatically retrieved and returned to the **REST call without writing any controller or service.**

In this case, how do you access @Autowire from @Entity

Comment: The question you linked to looks like the right answer to me. Don’t do it.

Comment: What does that even mean? How do I get access to another class if I don't do it? It doens't even make sense

Comment: Entity should be used only for storage, not for logic. It is a bad design. You might have a millions of entities, and you plan to store them all in your spring context ? Actionally, if you inject service field in your entities somehow, how will you serialize it ?

Comment: If you call entities within a service method, the transaction boundaries are well defined. If you call services from a domain model then you get a random hodgepodge of transactions.

Comment: Please check this blog : https://www.journaldev.com/17034/spring-data-jpa

Comment: Can you share some of the code base to understand what are you trying to achieve ? Like from where are you calling entity and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate `total` based on some calculation by `fields` of `Entity` you can use [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) also you can take a look [@Formula hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula). For example:

```
@Formula(value = "credit * rate")
private Double total;
```